# Restlet serving static content - Android

Tags: android, rest, uri, restlet

I'm building up a restlet server on my android app. I'm using the RESTlet android API from [restlet.org](http://restlet.org/)
I've done most part of it (rest), I can go to `myAndroidPhoneIP:port/something/else` and it will process my `get` `request` with no problems at all.

Now my problem is with serving static pages. If I go to m`yAndroidPhoneIP:port/static/index.html` it will load the `index` file but not the `images`, `css` and such external files.

I'm quite sure the problem is withing the routers class but I've spent the whole day trying to find the mistake to no success.

My static pages are in the (ecplise) assets folder, `/assets/web_resources`

Here is my code:

**My `router` class**

```
public class ContactsRouter extends Router {

    private static final String TAG = "ContactsRouter";

    private final ContactRestlet contactRestlet;
    private final DefaultTargetRestlet defaultTargetRestlet;
    private final ContactListRestlet contactListRestlet;
    private final PhotoRestlet photoRestlet;
    private final PhotoThumbnailRestlet photoThumbnailRestlet;
    private final StaticContentRestlet staticContentRestlet;

    public ContactsRouter(Context appContext ) {
        contactRestlet = new ContactRestlet(appContext);
        defaultTargetRestlet = new DefaultTargetRestlet();
        contactListRestlet = new ContactListRestlet(appContext);
        photoRestlet = new PhotoRestlet(appContext);
        photoThumbnailRestlet = new PhotoThumbnailRestlet(appContext);
        staticContentRestlet = new StaticContentRestlet(appContext);

        this.attach("/contacts", contactListRestlet); // To list all contacts
        this.attach("/contacts/{uid}", contactRestlet); // To show details about a specific contact
        this.attach("/contact/{uid}/photo", photoRestlet); // {uid} must correspond to a valid raw contact id
        this.attach("/contact/{uid}/photo/thumbnail", photoThumbnailRestlet);
        this.attach("/web_resources/{uid}", staticContentRestlet); // Filename is the static file to send to the user's browser
        //this.attachDefault(defaultTargetRestlet);
    }
```

**My StaticContent class**

```
public class StaticContentRestlet extends Restlet{

private Context context;
private static final String TAG = "StaticContent";
private static final String url = "web_resources/";

public StaticContentRestlet(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}



@Override
public void handle(Request request, Response response) {

    String type = request.getMethod().getName();
    String fileName = (String) request.getAttributes().get("uid");

    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("get"))
    {

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "path: " + url + fileName);
            Representation r = readStaticFile(url + fileName);
            response.setEntity(r);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            response.setStatus(new Status(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            response.setStatus(new Status(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL, e.getMessage()));
        } 
    }

}





public Representation readStaticFile(String fileName) throws NotFoundException, IOException
{
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
    Representation representation = new InputRepresentation(is);

    return representation;
}
```

}

And this is the output I get in logCat:

```
GET /web_resources/index.html   -   200 -   0   24  http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   -
GET /web_resources/css/bootstrap.min.css    -   404 439 0   5   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/css/bootstrap-fileupload.css -   404 439 0   4   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/css/unicorn.grey.css -   404 439 0   7   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/css/unicorn.main.css -   404 439 0   6   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css    -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css -   404 439 0   14  http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/css/jquery.pnotify.default.css   -   404 439 0   3   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/css/font-awesome.css -   404 439 0   3   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/css/jquery.pnotify.default.icons.css -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/excanvas.min.js   -   404 439 0   3   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/css/main.css -   404 439 0   3   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/jquery.min.js -   404 439 0   8   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js   -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/bootstrap.min.js  -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/jquery.tr.js  -   404 439 0   6   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js   -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/unicorn.js    -   404 439 0   3   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js  -   404 439 0   12  http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/dictionary.js -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/breadcrumbs-obj.js    -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/jquery.pnotify.min.js -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/jquery.cookie.js  -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/jquery.form.js    -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/angular.min.js    -   404 439 0   5   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/angular-route.min.js  -   404 439 0   3   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/angular-resource.min.js   -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/angular-sanitize.min.js   -   404 439 0   3   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/transfercontacts/services.js  -   404 439 0   3   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/transfercontacts/transfercontacts.js  -   404 439 0   4   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/js/transfercontacts/module.js    -   404 439 0   2   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
GET /web_resources/img/loader.gif   -   404 439 0   3   http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36   http://10.17.1.72:8080/web_resources/index.html
```

As you can see, it is trying to load the css, js, etc files but it can't load them. I get 404 on all of them, only index.html is loaded.

Here is a screenshot taken from chrome "Inspect Element".[image: output from chrome]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the filename used where the asset is loaded is incorrect.

What does the log report `Log.d(TAG, "path: " + url + fileName);` report when the url is: web_resources/css/bootstrap.min.css ?

Does the (url + fileName) become /web_resources/web_resources/css/bootstrap.min.css ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you mean. Could you be more precise please?

Comment: Could you post the output of the Log.d(TAG, "path: " + url + fileName) output ?

Comment: Here is the ouput: `path: web_resources/index.html`

Comment: ah, I see. So the StaticContentRestlet is only being called once and the rest of the time you get a 404 error.

Comment: Do you need something like: this.attach("/web_resources/*", staticContentRestlet); perhaps.

Comment: Sorry. I'm no help. I haven't used restlets before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you attach the Restlet that will handle the static content.

```
=> attach("/web_resources/{uid}", staticContentRestlet);
```

the uid variable by default catch a single segment. of a URI, that is to say everything between two "/" characters or the last segment of the URI.

If you want to catch single file name such as "index.html", and relative paths such as "css/bootstrap.min.css", take one of these options:

1. update the type of path variable in order to catch the remaining part
2. define two routes

That is to say, in term of code:

1:

```
TemplateRoute route = this.attach("/web_resources/{uid}", staticContentRestlet);
Variable var = route.getTemplate().getVariables().get("uid");
var.setType(Variable.TYPE_ALL);
```

2:

```
this.attach("/web_resources/{uid}", staticContentRestlet);
this.attach("/web_resources/{dir}/{uid}", staticContentRestlet);
```

and check the "dir" variable inside your StaticContentRestlet.